# files gets corrupted after uploading via ftp_put in php

Tags: php, file-upload

After i upload any file via ftp_put in php on a server,the file gets uploaded but the file gets corrupted on the server.

following code was used to upload files.

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $local_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $ftp_path = 'path/newfolder';
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $usr = 'userid';
    $pwd = 'password';
    $host = 'server_ip';
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die("Cannot connect to host");
    ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path . '/' . $filename, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
    print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
}
}
?>
```

I tried jpeg,xls etc...but i cannot open this files after uploading.

Comment: What do you mean under "can't open after uploading"? Are you trying to do that manually with something like FileZilla or what? What happens instead file being shown?

Comment: i try to download it or directly view it via filezilla ...it shows file corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what may cause that issue, but suppose you need to try upload file after [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
$local_file = "some/tmp/storage/path/$filename";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $local_file)) {
   $ftp_path = 'path/newfolder';
   $usr = 'userid';
   $pwd = 'password';
   $host = 'server_ip';
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die("Cannot connect to host");
   ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
   $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path . '/' . $filename, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
   print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
   ulink($local_file); //remove temporary local file
} else {
   echo 'File upload error';
}
```

Also, ensure that file is really uploaded by checking `$_FILES["file"]["error"]`. It should be equal to `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` (Other error [codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))

Comment: i tried the above code but it says that "move_uploaded_file(some/tmp/storage/path/Koala.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in "some path"". and also when i used my original code using ftp_put the size of the file gets reduced...like around 800kb file shrinks to 4kb..

Comment: You must create directories where file will be placed with move_uploaded_file. So, you must have folder `some` in the same dir where your script is, `tmp` inside it, `storage` inside `tmp` and `path` inside `tmp`

Comment: FTP_BINARY was enough for me